# Proper way to delete an array of pointers

Tags: c++, free

I have an array of pointers (that I created by calling `new ptr*[size]`). All of these pointers point to an object that was also put on the heap.

What is the proper way to delete the array and all new'd ptr's?

This is what I do now:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) delete array[i];
delete[] array; // Not sure since this double deletes array[0]
```

Does this do what I think it should?

Thanks

Comment: What is `ptr`?  This matters.

Comment: The correct way to do this is not to do this at all.  Prefer, perhaps, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`, which requires no manual cleanup at all.

Comment: let's say can be replaced with int here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Every pointer allocated with `new` gets a corresponding `delete`.  Every pointer allocated with `new []` gets a corresponding `delete []`.  That's really all you need to know.  Of course, when you have a dynamically allocated array which contains dynamically allocated pointers the deallocation must occur in reverse order.

So it follows that the correct idiom would be...

```
int main()
{
    int **container = new int*[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        container[i] = new int[size];

    // ... and to deallocate...
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        delete [] container[i];

    delete [] container;
}
```

And then of course I say "stop doing that" and recommend you use a `std::array` or `std::vector` (and the template type would be `unique_ptr<int>`).

Comment: (+1) whole answer, but, a plus for "reverse order". In theory, It doesn't matter the allocation/deallocation order, but, I agree that its more efficient, to deallocate in reverse order ...

Comment: @umlcat: Deallocation order does matter though.  In this example the expression `container[n]` would result in undefined behavior if `delete [] container` had already been called.

Comment: The part that I don't get is how 'delete [] container[0]' and 'delete [] container' not break since we are deleting with a pointer to the same thing

Comment: @jamesatha: `container[0]` is *not* the same thing as `container`.  I think you are confused because `container` is a pointer to the first element and so is `&container[0]`, but `container[0]` *is* actually the first element.  Not the same.

Comment: @EdS. Thanks, I forgot that!

Comment: Note that for this code to be correct, exception handling is required to clean up correctly if an exception is thrown by any `new` expression (either due to allocation failure or construction failure).  Such exception handling code is tedious and difficult to verify as correct, which is why one should not write code like this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that does what you think it should. Since you did `new` for each element, you have to `delete` each element. And since you did `new[]` for the entire array, you need to `delete[]` the entire array.

As @djechlin rightly says in the comments, there's not really enough information to go on, but I'm presuming your prior code is something like this:

```
int** array = new int*[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  array[i] = new int;
}
```

Note that array is not actually an array type. It is a "pointer to pointer to int" and the array of pointers it points to was allocated with `new[]`. That's why you need to `delete[]` it.

Comment: This is not clear from OP's question - don't know how `ptr` is allocated, and I only see one `new` in his code, should be only one `delete`.

Comment: but doesn't delete array[0] and delete array point to the same thing?

Comment: @djechlin "All of these pointers point to an object that was also put on the heap."

Comment: Put on the heap in a constructor and removed in a destructor possibly?  Type of `ptr` matters.

Comment: @djechlin destructors are called throught delete, aren't they?

Comment: @jamesatha Nope. `array[0]` gives you the pointer which is the first element of the array, and `delete array[0]` destroys the object it points to. Your `array` is presumably of type `ptr**`, so doing `delete array` deletes what it is pointing to, which is the array.

Comment: @AdelBoutros as stated yes okay, that's what the object itself being on the heap means.  More accurately, "it was put on the heap" does not mean "and I should delete it."  Could have been put on the heap elsewhere in the program, e.g. by a smart pointer that is now exposing its raw resource, so there is not enough information to tell if this is the proper way to delete and OP must be aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. First you have to free the object each pointer in the array points to, then you have to free the array itself. In that order. If you reverse the order you'll have no reference to the objects and will leak a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first you delete each object to which elements of array point, and then you delete array of pointers itself. If you want to check your memory management, you can use tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), they will be able to spot most errors.